# Recovery mode wouldn't show up after installing cyanogenmod 13

Tags: cyanogenmod, 6.0-marshmallow, recovery-mode, boot

I have rooted and installed Cyanogenmod 13 in Lenovo vibe K5 (previously it has lenovo vibe k5 lollipop version) and since then i am trying to enter into  recovery mode by pressing "Volume up +Power button" but Its not going  into recovery mode. When i press "Volume up +Power button" it stucks at Lenovo boot logo. I have checked advance  reboot option as well in developer option.

Comment: Did you backed up your previous ROM ? What was your previous ROM ? Is device rooted ? Which recovery you have used previously? Please mention these informations to question.

Comment: yeah i have backed up my previous rom, it was Lenovo vibe K5 default rom (Lollipop) and i have rooted my device.

Comment: which recovery mode you have used?

Comment: @RahulGopi TWRP

Comment: You can set ROOT access in CM13 by enabling Developer options. Go to settings -> About Phone Then tap on Build Number. Then, go to developer options, in that click on Root access, select Apps and ADB. You can follow the previous steps for TWRP install again .

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by enabling developer options and enabling the android debugger so then when you need to go to recovery option, you will just have to press the power button and tap on restart you will get multiple option just choose recovery, device will boot up into recovery mode.